# I need help in installing ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

I'm using HP pavilion g6 laptop with AMD processor. Previously I had Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 running perfectly in wubi.
Now I want to install ubuntu 13.10 in the same manner.
It extracts some file on C:\ubuntu directory and also shows booting option in windows grub but when I choose to boot ubuntu it returns an error like "unable to find media containing live file system". If I insert USB/DVD then it boots but in a live session only.

it also gives me  option to install ubuntu 13.10 . I tried this option then ubuntu cant detect my windows partition.

I have four partitions. Apart from this one partition is shown as logical drive and other three as primary partitions.
I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ubuntu and upgrade it from there. I upgrade this way, and it doesn't even touch Windows.

Boot into Ubuntu. Log in if necessary, then from Unity Dash search for updates. Let it do it's thing, then it should show an upgrade dialog saying something along the lines of "However, Ubuntu 13.10 is available." This should work.

Comment: thank bro ...but i dont have ubuntu installed so upgrade is not a way....